# Set up jekyll on windows

Tags: ruby, windows, jekyll

I try to set up jekyll on window10 (x64)

```
Ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x64-mingw32]
gem -v
2.6.6


D:\myblog>jekyll serve
Configuration file: D:/myblog/_config.yml
            Source: D:/myblog
       Destination: D:/myblog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
Error reading file C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/default.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/default.html
Error reading file C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/page.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/page.html
Error reading file C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/post.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/post.html
```

Can someone help me to fix it?

Comment: Do you have two different disk drives? I noticed that your blog is located on the D drive and the jekyll command is looking on your C drive for Ruby. I want to make sure that you actually are using different drives.

Are you able to run the `which` equivalent for windows for ruby, gem and jekyll to show where those scripts are running from? I am wondering if one of those commands is referencing a different Ruby install.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Following the path shown in the command line (for me it was) :

`C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/default.html`

and copying the `_layouts`,  `_includes` and `_sass` folders manually did the thing for me. Although this is not a permanent solution as there seems some bug which is preventing jekyll to copy file from the directory shown in the error.
Hope this helps you too for now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to your **Project directory** and **Ruby installation**, being on different drives (i.e. **D:** vs. **C:**).

To fix, you can simply create a (junction) link to `C:/Ruby22-x64` from the location `D:/Ruby22-x64`.

Commands you need to enter:

```
D:
cd /
mklink /J "Ruby22-x64" "C:/Ruby22-x64"
```